# Android Regex Pattern Incode UTF-8

Tags: android, html, json, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying this code in android for catching (.+?) with matcher.group(1):

```
String html = doc.html().toString();

                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)caption\"(?is):(?is)\"(.+?)\",(?is)\"",
                            Pattern.DOTALL);
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
                        if (m.find()){
                            text_main = m.group(1);
                        }
```

but sometimes it doesn't work. I think it can be caused by incode. so:

1. If I think true, what can i do for this problem?(make regex for utf-8)
2. If I'm wrong, so what can i do?. I'm trying to get a string in a json object. the json code is placed in a script in a html page.

Comment: Why are you repeating `(?is)`? You only need to declare that once at the beginning of the pattern. Also, it is inefficient. Try `"(?is)caption\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]*(?:\"(?!,)[\"]*)*)\"\\s*,\\s*\""`.

Comment: @stribizhev i always find myself learning something from everyone single one of your comments/answers.

Comment: @iismathwizard: You might be surprised, but I also am learning a lot here on SO, and the comment above is based on something I learnt from Casimir et Hippolyte. That is why it is difficult to quit SO :).

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work!

Comment: isn't encoding effective on my problem?

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" ... Ok, so will you please provide a subject text that doesn't match?